# SQL Server Union Group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to group two SELECTS that were joined by the UNION command, and group by the Data column, but I noticed that the Data column is returning two equal values, when it should only return one, so I was thinking about grouping this UNION again by the Date, can someone help me? Thank you very much in advance

Code:

```
SELECT
    Tab_Dados_Producao.E3TimeStamp AS Data,
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Tab_Dados_Producao.Maquina = 'PH_07' THEN Tab_Dados_Producao.Valor ELSE 0 END),2) As 'PH_07',
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Tab_Dados_Producao.Maquina = 'PH_08' THEN Tab_Dados_Producao.Valor ELSE 0 END),2) As 'PH_08',
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Tab_Dados_Producao.Maquina = 'PH_09' THEN Tab_Dados_Producao.Valor ELSE 0 END),2) As 'PH_09',
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Tab_Dados_Producao.Maquina = 'MDS' THEN Tab_Dados_Producao.Valor ELSE 0 END),2) As 'MDS',
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Tab_Dados_Producao.Maquina = 'MCCMP' THEN  Tab_Dados_Producao.Valor ELSE 0 END),2) As 'MCCMP',
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Tab_Dados_Producao.Maquina = 'MDCMP'THEN Tab_Dados_Producao.Valor ELSE 0 END),2) As 'MDCMP',
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Tab_Dados_Producao.Maquina = 'MCF'THEN Tab_Dados_Producao.Valor ELSE 0 END),2) As 'MCF',
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Tab_Dados_Producao.Maquina = 'MDF'  THEN Tab_Dados_Producao.Valor ELSE 0 END),2) As 'MDF',
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Tab_Dados_Producao.Maquina = 'ESC_04'  THEN Tab_Dados_Producao.Valor ELSE 0 END),2) As 'ESC_04',
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Tab_Dados_Producao.Maquina = 'ESC_RET' THEN Tab_Dados_Producao.Valor ELSE 0 END),2) As 'ESC_RET'
FROM 
    [E3_CERAL].[dbo].[Tab_Dados_Producao]
WHERE
    MONTH((Tab_Dados_Producao.E3TimeStamp)) = '8' 
    AND DAY((Tab_Dados_Producao.E3TimeStamp)) = '16'
GROUP BY 
    Tab_Dados_Producao.E3TimeStamp

UNION 

SELECT
    Tab_Dados_Escolha.E3TimeStamp AS Data,
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Tab_Dados_Escolha.Maquina = 'PH_07' THEN Tab_Dados_Escolha.Metrica ELSE 0 END),2) As 'PH_07',
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Tab_Dados_Escolha.Maquina = 'PH_08' THEN Tab_Dados_Escolha.Metrica ELSE 0 END),2) As 'PH_08',
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Tab_Dados_Escolha.Maquina = 'PH_09' THEN Tab_Dados_Escolha.Metrica ELSE 0 END),2) As 'PH_09',
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Tab_Dados_Escolha.Maquina = 'MDS' THEN Tab_Dados_Escolha.Metrica ELSE 0 END),2) As 'MDS',
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Tab_Dados_Escolha.Maquina = 'MCCMP' THEN Tab_Dados_Escolha.Metrica ELSE 0 END),2) As 'MCCMP',
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Tab_Dados_Escolha.Maquina = 'MDCMP'THEN Tab_Dados_Escolha.Metrica ELSE 0 END),2) As 'MDCMP',
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Tab_Dados_Escolha.Maquina = 'MCF'THEN Tab_Dados_Escolha.Metrica ELSE 0 END),2) As 'MCF',
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Tab_Dados_Escolha.Maquina = 'MDF'  THEN Tab_Dados_Escolha.Metrica ELSE 0 END),2) As 'MDF',
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Tab_Dados_Escolha.Maquina = 'ESC_04'  THEN Tab_Dados_Escolha.Metrica ELSE 0 END),2) As 'ESC_04',
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Tab_Dados_Escolha.Maquina = 'ESC_RET' THEN Tab_Dados_Escolha.Metrica ELSE 0 END),2) As 'ESC_RET'
FROM 
    [E3_CERAL].[dbo].[Tab_Dados_Escolha]
WHERE
    MONTH((Tab_Dados_Escolha.E3TimeStamp)) = '8' 
    AND DAY((Tab_Dados_Escolha.E3TimeStamp)) = '16'
GROUP BY 
    Tab_Dados_Escolha.E3TimeStamp
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you need to union the data first, then group and aggregate.

Comment: Thanks, do you know some example?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1):

Of course I have no way to test the following but see if this is the output you are expecting - union the data from both tables first in a CTE, then aggregate the result:

```
with u as (
    select E3TimeStamp as Data, Maquina, Valor
    from dbo.Tab_Dados_Producao
    where Month((E3TimeStamp)) = '8' and Day((E3TimeStamp)) = '16'
    union 
    select E3TimeStamp, Maquina, Metrica 
    from dbo.Tab_Dados_Escolha
    where Month((E3TimeStamp)) = '8' and Day((E3TimeStamp)) = '16'
)

select Data,
  Round(Sum(case when Maquina = 'PH_07'     then Valor else 0 end),2) as PH_07,
  Round(Sum(case when Maquina = 'PH_08'     then Valor else 0 end),2) as PH_08,
  Round(Sum(case when Maquina = 'PH_09'     then Valor else 0 end),2) as PH_09,
  Round(Sum(case when Maquina = 'MDS'       then Valor else 0 end),2) as MDS,
  Round(Sum(case when Maquina = 'MCCMP'     then Valor else 0 end),2) as MCCMP,
  Round(Sum(case when Maquina = 'MDCMP'     then Valor else 0 end),2) as MDCMP,
  Round(Sum(case when Maquina = 'MCF'       then Valor else 0 end),2) as MCF,
  Round(Sum(case when Maquina = 'MDF'       then Valor else 0 end),2) as MDF,
  Round(Sum(case when Maquina = 'ESC_04'    then Valor else 0 end),2) as ESC_04,
  Round(Sum(case when Maquina = 'ESC_RET'   then Valor else 0 end),2) as ESC_RET'
from u
group by data
```

Note that you shouldn't be using 3-part names - you already specified the database when you connected to SQL Server; also you shouldn't be quoting your column aliases - if you need to cater for special characters eg spaces or if using reserved words you wrap the name in [braces], but in your case it's fine as-is.